# Creating mysql view with an existing table name on every http request for roles purposes

Tags: php, mysql, performance, view

I need to add permissions and roles to my app, But I wouldn't like to go file by file method by method, The kind of roles I need is for example showing only specific records from database depending on the user connected.
Exemple: I have a `"contracts_types"`, And `"contracts"` table, When listing `"contracts"` I use a `JOIN` with `"contracts_types"` so that I show the contract type as well, So If the contract type doesn't exist, The contract wouldn't be shown, What I'd like to do, Is to create some sort of a view every time user is connected, The view should contain an image of the table with a filter:

```
CREATE VIEW contracts_types AS SELECT * FROM contracts_types WHERE contractTypeId IN( USER AUTHORISED CONTRACTS TYPES IDS )
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, If it is, Is there a performance issues creating the same view on every http request for each user connected, I mean , Other users will be connected and the same view name will be created, I'm looking for a similar solution where I don't need to go to every select statement I made and add the `contractTypeId` filter, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"So If the contract type doesn't exist, The contract wouldn't be shown" -- That's what this does:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM contracts AS c
    JOIN contract_types AS ct  ON ct.type = c.contract_type
```

Or is your question more involved?

You cannot do any kind of filtering on *rows* of a table without having some kind of filter in the query.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM contracts AS c
    JOIN contract_types AS ct  ON ct.type = c.contract_type
    JOIN role_can_see AS ucs  ON rcs.type = c.contract_type
    WHERE rcs.role = ?
```

(and fill in the role that the user belongs to)

If the user is in multiple roles, then

```
    WHERE rcs.role IN (...)
```

But this is effectively implementing "roles" yourself.

Comment: This is actually the issue, I have thousands of queries and I don't find it a smart solution to go over every single query and add that filter, I'd like to do it automaticly, I have the query method wrapped So I can do some string manipulation to add that filter but there are too many cases and it would be almost impossible to deal with it that way.